# Correlation between two raster images with output as a raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, correlation

I have two different rasters, one denoting the climatic parameter and the other denoting the drought impact. Now I want to estimate the correlation between these raster datasets; the output I want is in raster format. I tried the code below, but it is giving me one single correlation coefficient value. What would be the change in the code, that would give me a raster output with different correlation coefficient values for different pixels?

```
var band1 = ee.Image('users/swadhinakoley/Exposure');
var band2 = ee.Image('users/swadhinakoley/Sensitivity');
var band3 = ee.Image('users/swadhinakoley/Adaptive_Capacity');
var band4 = ee.Image('users/swadhinakoley/Vulnerability');



var stack = band1.addBands(band2).addBands(band3).addBands(band4);
Map.addLayer(stack, {}, 'stack');

var imgRegress = stack.select(['b1_2','b1_3']);


//Findind the correlation between bands
var corr = imgRegress.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(),
  geometry: Area,
  scale: 250
});

print(corr, 'corr');
```

I am giving an example of the desired output below in the image taken from [Here](https://statnmap.com/2018-01-27-spatial-correlation-between-rasters/).

[image: Correlation Map]

Comment: You can't do a per-pixel "correlation" because at each location you'd only have 2 numbers and correlation can't be computed on only 2 numbers.  You need some other statistic.

Comment: I have given an example above there. Can you please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What's being done in that link, is a windowed operation computing the correlation of small patches.  You do windowed operations with reduceNeighborhood.

```
stack.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(), ee.Kernel.square(2.5))
```

Comment: @Swadhina, just keep in mind that you will need to think about these types of correlations differently because, now there is a spatial term in play. You have a distance lagged correlation that may change with specification of a different kernel scale or type (eg., uniform, Gaussian, Epanechnikov). Although, I am not sure that different kernel distributions are available in `reduceNeighborhood`.